# Modifying a JQuery filter file

Tags: php, jquery, filter

I've modified (visually) a nifty JQuery table filter plugin that lets you filter text as you type - I'm sure you've all seen it done before.

My working page is here: http://www.studentbytes.co.uk/recipes.php

The original file is located here: http://www.picnet.com.au/resources/tablefilter/demo.htm

The issue I'm having is that I want to remove the input fields added at the top of each column but all my attempts to edit the original code so far have resulted in script errors. The syntax errors are on line 174 after commenting out this (which is I presume the only piece that achieves adding inputs):

```
{case "text":$filter$$3_header$$2_header$$inline_297_td$$1$$=$goog$dom$createDom$$("in­put",{type:"text",id:"filter_"+$colIdx$$inline_296$$,"class":"filter",title:$JSCo­mpiler_StaticMethods_getFilterDom$self$$inline_295_element$$inline_303_headerText­$$.options.filterToolTipMessage}
```

I know this means that you will have to get down and dirty in the source code but can anyone help me out?

Also, has anyone ever initiated plugins of this type and managed to implement pagination? Does the filter plugin like paginated content?

Thank you for all the help everyone. I decided that this plugin was worth providing more trouble than pleasure to stopped using it. I found a brilliant alternative at net tuts though for future reference called "Using jQuery To Manipulate and Filter Data" (I don't have the privileges to post more links yet).

Comment: Can you try to isolate what code is causing you problems?

Comment: Hi, I know that the plugin adds the input with a class of 'filter' but trying to remove that function/piece of code from the Javascript file always seems throw up errors - I think there are several links to this function in the file but my limited knowledge of Javascript debugging doesn't help.

Comment: Can you maybe add the error messages you get?

Comment: They are just 'syntax error on line ...' when I'm removing the code in the editor. It's particularly tricky because the code has been compiled without breaks etc.

Comment: Well then add the lines that provide the syntax error.

Comment: The errors are on line 174 after commenting out this (which is I presume the only piece that achieves adding inputs): {case "text":$filter$$3_header$$2_header$$inline_297_td$$1$$=$goog$dom$createDom$$("input",{type:"text",id:"filter_"+$colIdx$$inline_296$$,"class":"filter",title:$JSCompiler_StaticMethods_getFilterDom$self$$inline_295_element$$inline_303_headerText$$.options.filterToolTipMessage}

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted makes the brackets unbalanced. You commented out:

```
{
  case "text":
    $filter$$3_header$$2_header$$inline_297_td$$1$$ = 
      $goog$dom$createDom$$("input",{            
        type:    "text",
        id:      "filter_" + $colIdx$$inline_296$$,
        "class": "filter",
        title:   $JSCo­mpiler_StaticMethods_getFilterDom$self$$inline_295_element$$inline_303_headerText­$$
           .options.filterToolTipMessage
       }
```

You are missing a `) }` at the end.

Comment: Hi, I added the extra bracket and braces but I'm still receiving the error. I'm putting it after "...filterToolTipMessage}" and before "...);
break a;..."

Comment: Try to post a block of code with what you commented out. I can't guess what's wrong with your code without seeing it. Also StackOverflow pro-tip: Try to provide as much information about your answer upfront namely: exact text of error messages and the code where they come from. Also don't be afraid to edit your answer to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could put this in the javascript ot be execute after the DOM loads

```
$('.filter').hide()
```

Comment: Ah yes of course. Would you not advise touching the original file then?

Comment: I would say that sometimes the route with least resistance is best - but depends what you want to get out of it. You can learn a lot by re-coding the whole thing from scratch, and might face scorn of coding-snobs if you use jquery to remove DOM elements after loading.

Comment: Hi, hiding '.filter' does the job but for some reason the original code adds a duplicate input field and only the first is added. Ideally I would rewrite this and have a proper go at learning Javascript and Jquery myself but this is for a University project so time is of the essence!